# Is there a Power Bi Dax formula to show a result based on multiple conditions?

Tags: powerbi, dax, multiple-conditions

I have a Table which contains the following columns:

```
|       Feature       |       Date       |    Update | hours|
|---------------------|------------------|-----------|------|
|General              |2018-10-02        |V1         |0     |
|General              |2018-10-02        |V1         |0     |
|General              |2018-10-02        |V1         |0     |
|General              |2018-10-02        |V1         |0     |
|General              |2018-10-02        |V1         |0     |
|PvP                  |2018-10-02        |V1         |3     |
|PvP                  |2018-10-02        |V1         |2     |
|PvP                  |2018-10-02        |V1         |1     |
|PvP                  |2018-10-02        |V1         |1     |
|General              |2018-10-02        |V1         |0     |
|General              |2018-10-02        |V1         |7     |
|General              |2018-10-02        |V1         |0     |
|General              |2018-10-02        |V1         |0     |
|Visual               |2018-10-02        |V1         |7     |
|General              |2018-10-15        |V1         |0     |
|General              |2018-10-15        |V1         |0     |
|General              |2018-10-15        |V1         |0     |
|Visual               |2018-10-15        |V1         |7     |
|Visual               |2018-10-15        |V1         |2     |
|General              |2018-10-16        |V1         |1     |
```

Using this example i want to add a custom column that can count the number of runs executed for each feature based on the following criteria:

> Calculate the sum of minutes based on feature for each day and:
>   For example if today's sum is higher than yesterday's, count as 1 run else count as zero.

Below is an example

```
|       Feature       |       Date       |    Update | hours|No of runs|
|---------------------|------------------|-----------|------|----------|
|General              |2018-10-02        |V1         |0     |1
|General              |2018-10-02        |V1         |0     |1
|General              |2018-10-02        |V1         |0     |1
|General              |2018-10-02        |V1         |0     |1
|General              |2018-10-02        |V1         |0     |1
|PvP                  |2018-10-02        |V1         |3     |1
|PvP                  |2018-10-02        |V1         |2     |1
|PvP                  |2018-10-02        |V1         |1     |1
|PvP                  |2018-10-02        |V1         |1     |1
|General              |2018-10-02        |V1         |0     |1
|General              |2018-10-02        |V1         |7     |1
|General              |2018-10-02        |V1         |0     |1
|General              |2018-10-02        |V1         |0     |1
|Visual               |2018-10-02        |V1         |7     |1
|General              |2018-10-15        |V1         |0     |0
|General              |2018-10-15        |V1         |0     |0
|General              |2018-10-15        |V1         |0     |0
|Visual               |2018-10-15        |V1         |7     |1
|Visual               |2018-10-15        |V1         |2     |1
|General              |2018-10-16        |V1         |1     |1
```

The run counter should start from 1 for each feature.

So far i have tried to use the following formula but it gives incorrect information:

> No_of_runs = CALCULATE(COUNTA('table'[Feature]),Filter('Table','Table'[Feature]=EARLIER('Table'[Feature]) && 'Table'[Date] > EARLIER('Table'[Date] && 'Table'[Time Invested(hours)] > Earlier('Table'[Time Invested(hours)])))

Comment: for one thing, you're missing a closing parenthesis after "EARLIER('Table'[Date]  "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I've fully understood the logic, but try this as a calculated column:

```
No_of_runs = 
VAR DateToday = 
    Table1[Date]
VAR MinutesToday = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( Table1[Time Invested (hours)] ),
        FILTER ( 
            ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Feature] ),
            Table1[Date] = DateToday
        )
    )
VAR MinutesYesterday = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( Table1[Time Invested (hours)] ),
        FILTER ( 
            ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Feature] ),
            Table1[Date] = DateToday - 1
        )
    )
RETURN 
    IF ( 
        MinutesToday > MinutesYesterday,
        1,
        0
    )
```

Edit: here's a worked example PBIX file; https://pwrbi.com/so_55588315/

Comment: The above formula is displaying 0 runs for the entire column. My main goal is basically to count each time addition as a new run on a daily basis for each feature. So for example if 2 days ago i had for feature x 10 hours logged and yesterday I've added another half an hour then that counts as a new run, if today i won't add any time for that feature then the run counter should display zero for today. I hope it makes sense

Comment: It doesn't make sense, to me. My answer gave your expected outcome, for your sample data. Can you please [edit] your question to show some clearer sample data - a clear sample of inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: I have added a small part of the data

Comment: Basically the logic Stands like this: 1. Compare the sum of hours between two dates based on feature. 2. If the value of the most recent date is higher than the previous date, count as 1 else count as zero.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what my answer does?

Comment: Not in the example file I've added to my answer... So, something is different in your data model, to the example data you've posted in your question.

Comment: I had to change the date format for some reason and then it worked. Thanks a lot !!